# R - Preventing data type change in a data frame column

Tags: r

If you use a data frame as a data strucutre in a larger program it's sometimes annoying to get errors if a certain data type is expected but in some other part the data type of a data frame column was changed "by accident".

```
> df=data.frame(x=c(1,2,3))
> typeof(df$x)
[1] "double"
> df$x[1]="a"
> typeof(df$x)
[1] "character"
```

I want to fix the data type of column x so that the assignment of a character results in a warning or error. Is there aconvenient way to do it?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. A column of a `data.frame` is a list this is why you have this behavior. I'm wondering  in which context you would not want this feature? Besides you could always test if a specific column is of type `character` and generate an error if it is the case

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Mainly, I use this particular data.frame as a sort of data base. I already try to handle this data frame only with functions that have some sort of check. But as a double check and more convenience, I'm looking for automatic compatability check like you have in a SQL insert statement.

Comment: if your first check work as intended no need to double check. Note that you are updating and note inserting. so an update function could check the type of the column it is supposed to update. coerce the values in this type and update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I agree with the comment of DJJ: it's probably better to check as you go along, rather than to rely on a warning.

However, everyone that uses R has probably at one stage been caught-out by an unexpected type change as you describe.

Here's how you could implement a warning when this happens.  But please note: there is a performance penalty for this, so it's best suited to troublshooting, and probably not a good thing to routinely use in your code...

We can use an 'active binding' to run a custom function each time a value is assigned to our chosen variable.  In this case, our function will check if the type has changed, and if it has, it will print a warning.

```
trackTypeChange = function(x) {
    x_name=x
    makeActiveBinding(x,
        local({ typeofx=""; function(v) {
            if (!missing(v)) {
                if (!all((tov=unlist(lapply(v,typeof)))==typeofx)) {
                    typeofx<<-tov
                    warning(paste("setting type of",x_name,"to",paste(typeofx,collapse=",")),call.=FALSE)
                }
                x<<-v
            } 
            x
        }}),
        .GlobalEnv
    )
}
```

Let's say we want to track inadvertant changes to the types of the columns of `my_tracked_df`:

```
trackTypeChange('my_tracked_df')
```

So:

```
my_tracked_df=data.frame(a=1:10,b=1:10+0.1,c=letters[1:10])
# Warning message:
# setting type of my_tracked_df to integer,double,integer

my_tracked_df$a=11:20 # no type change, no warning

my_tracked_df$a=21:30+0.1 
# Warning message:
# setting type of my_tracked_df to double,double,integer
```

But: there is a performance impact (from always checking the type) - roughly 3x slower to assign than to an identical non-tracked dataframe:

```
my_untracked_df=data.frame(a=1:10,b=1:10+0.1,c=letters[1:10])
system.time(for(i in 1:10000){my_tracked_df$b=my_tracked_df$b+0.1})
#   user  system elapsed
#  0.558   0.006   0.563
system.time(for(i in 1:10000){my_untracked_df$b=my_untracked_df$b+0.1})
#   user  system elapsed
#  0.187   0.001   0.187
```

Comment: Thank you, I like that solution and since performance is not really an issue for me, I can go for it.  My other approach was to define an S4 class representation that mimics the data frame and checks for the correct data type. However this seems to be very unhandy when you often change things and you need to build a lot of methods for that class (and I'm not really an experienced programmer...). Just out of curiosity, do you know if it was possible to kindof overload the assignment operator for data frames globally and incorporate the data type check there?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but this will 'trigger' every time you assign to any element of your data frame(s), including inside loops or functions, so it has a terrible performance impact, even if the only thing you do is run an ```if``` and exit...

Comment: Sorry - wasn't clear in previous comment & timed-out while trying to edit it: it's possible to overload the assignment operator(s), but I don't know if it's possible to do this only for data frames: this would be an interesting Q.  If you do it globally (for all data types) then the performance penalty is quite big...